# How can I get correct function address on Aix?

Tags: gcc, aix

see a simple code below:

```
int foo(int a)
{
   return a;
}
int main() {
   printf("%x\n", foo);
   printf("%x\n", &foo);
   printf("%x\n", *foo);  
   foo(1);  
}
```

They all displayed the same value:

```
0x20453840 
0x20453840 
0x20453840
```

I used gdb to check foo() entry point is:

```
(gdb) p foo
$1 = {int (int)} 0x100003d8 <foo>
```

the value 0x20453840 is actually foo() pointer of pointer:

```
(gdb) p /x *0x20453850
$3 = 0x100003d8
(gdb) si              
   0x10000468      76         foo(1);
   0x10000464 <main+76>:        38 60 00 01     li      r3,1
=> 0x10000468 <main+80>:        4b ff ff 71     bl      0x100003d8 <foo>
(gdb) 
foo (a=541407312) at insertcode.c:57
57      {
=> 0x100003d8 <foo+0>:  93 e1 ff fc     stw     r31,-4(r1)
   0x100003dc <foo+4>:  94 21 ff e0     stwu    r1,-32(r1)
   0x100003e0 <foo+8>:  7c 3f 0b 78     mr      r31,r1
   0x100003e4 <foo+12>: 90 7f 00 38     stw     r3,56(r31)
(gdb)
```

So I think 0x100003d8 is the entry point.
I used gcc 4.6.2 to compile.
I have tow questions:

1. why different function address definition on AIX? is it related to gcc?
   I have to use gcc not xlC.
2. how to get real function address in C on AIX?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken a look at what's at `0x100003d8`? I'm no expert on *AIX* and related platform, but maybe there is stub function there? Can you post the disassembly at `0x100003d8`?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, I have add the 0x100003d8 disassembly partially, I think it is the entry point. Thank you.

Comment: I have a really bad feeling about *why* you (think you) need "the real address". For all practical purposes, `foo` *is* "the real address". Unless you want to write a disassembler or something similar, you should not bother with the "real" value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why different function address definition on AIX?

```
nm -Pg ./f_addr  | grep foo
```

Try this command, and you will see you have too symbols: `foo` and `.foo` One of them lives in the code segment (or text segment), the other, in the data segment.

The purpose is, indeed, creating an indirection in function calling; it is important when creating/using shared libraries.

> is it related to gcc? I have to use gcc not xlC.

No.

> How to get real function address in C on AIX?

Please clarify your question: what do you want to do with the 'real address'.

Comment: thank you.
I think i can get the direction entry point. I am porting a Linux tools into Aix, the code need the entry point to call its function at runtime.
I am using `void ** p = foo; void * p1 = *p;` is it correct?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special, `void *funptr= (void *)foo` will work just as it works in linux.